# Angular5: Spinner is not working perfectly on page load

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service, components

Following is my service where I emits two events `dataLoaded` and `loadingData` I want to show and hide GIF image when data is loading and loaded respectively, and in component I catch both events and change the value of Boolean variable. But when page loads first time initially loading GIF is not showing and when data loaded then GIF appeared and if I select filter to search then it works fine and also when I debug the code the value of `showLoading` updated successfully

**Service**

```
import { forwardRef, Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


    @Injectable()
    export class SearchService {
     loadingData = new EventEmitter();
        dataLoaded = new EventEmitter();
     pages: any = {};
        searchResults = [];
     search() {
            this.loadingData.emit("ShowLoading")
            this.performSearch().then(response => {
                this.searchResults = response.json();
                this.pages = this.searchResults['pages'];
                this.searchResults = this.searchResults['data'];
                this.resultsUpdated.emit('SearchResultsUpdated');
                this.dataLoaded.emit("HideLoading")
            }, error => {
                   this.dataLoaded.emit("HideLoading")
             });
        }
    }
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from '../../search.service';
/*import {Alert} from "../../alert.component";*/
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { SavedSearchComponent } from '../saved-search/saved-search.component';
@Component({
 selector: 'property-onion-search-results',
  templateUrl: './search-results.component.html'
})

export class SearchResultsComponent {
  @ViewChild('searchResultArea') resultsArea: ElementRef;
  searchResults: any[] = null;
  closeResult: string;
  view = 'regular';
  resultInformation: any[];
  filterString: string = "";
  resultCount: number = 0;
  numbers: any[] = null;
  showLoading;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService, private modalService: NgbModal) {

    this.searchService.resultsUpdated.subscribe(data => {
      this.searchResults = this.searchService.getResults();
      this.filterString = this.searchService.toString();
      this.resultCount = this.searchService.pages.total;
      var pages = this.searchService.pages.number_of_pages;
      if (this.searchService.pages.total > 25) {
        this.numbers = new Array(pages).fill(1).map((x, i) => i);
      } else {
        this.numbers = null;
      }
      this.resultsArea.nativeElement.click(); // THis is a hack to fix refresh issue of this area. This area doesn't get refreshed unless you click somewhere in the browser.          
    });

    this.searchService.loadingData.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("show")
      this.showLoading = true
    });
    this.searchService.dataLoaded.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("hide")
      this.showLoading = false
    });

  }
}
```

**html**

```
<img class="loading" *ngIf="showLoading" src="images/loader.gif"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For initial loading you should define **showLoading** directly in your component :

```
showLoading:boolean = true;
```